# How to generate PSHC carrier used in vocoders

Tags: filter-design, speech-processing, audio-processing, speech-synthesis

Vocoders are often used to acoustically simulate the information transmitted
by a cochlear implant. The different types of vocoders used in cochlear implants include noise-vocoding, sine-vocoding and pulse-spreading harmonic complexes as carrier in vocoders. How to generate pulse spreading harmonic complexes in matlab?

Comment: Hi! I think your question is very interesting in its core, but the way it's currently stated it explicitly asks for code written to a specification. We have a rule that makes these kinds of questions specifically off-topic! Could you, instead, describe what you've tried so far and where you're stuck? The [original paper](https://asa.scitation.org/doi/10.1121/1.4890642) has formulas (1) to (3), and a pretty well-written explanation what the formula elements are and how they are (some randomly) chosen. That's pretty much an instruction on how to implement this. Is this really signal processing,

Comment: and not more of a general matlab programming question?

Comment: In the paper" Pulse-spreading harmonic complex as an alternative carrier for vocoder
simulations of cochlear implants", it was written that "This function was obtained by generating broadband PSHCs having f0’s of 0.3 Hz and different rates. "How is this broadband PSHCs generated is not clear.

Comment: but as said, that's explicitly described in the original paper that "invented" PSHCs very well.